# Multiple exists queries not returning anything (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

When I run single exist query I get results as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `slasher_farming_mods` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `slasher_farming_brands` 
              WHERE `slasher_farming_mods`.`brand_id` = `slasher_farming_brands`.`id` 
                AND `brand_id` = '7' 
              ORDER BY `id` asc) 
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

When I run multiple exist queries, I don't get any results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `slasher_farming_mods` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `slasher_farming_brands` 
              WHERE `slasher_farming_mods`.`brand_id` = `slasher_farming_brands`.`id` 
                AND `brand_id` = '7' 
                ORDER BY `id` ASC) 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `slasher_farming_brands` 
              WHERE `slasher_farming_mods`.`brand_id` = `slasher_farming_brands`.`id` 
                AND `brand_id` = '24' 
              ORDER BY `id` ASC) 
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Tried using debugbar in laravel to see if my query is taking too long, but it takes less than 1ms. What could be wrong here, I tried to run these query also directly inside phpmyadmin but still no results with more than one where exists.

Query is populated by foreach loop in laravel.

```
   foreach ($brands as $brand){
            $query->whereHas('brand', function($q) use ($brand){
                $q->where('brand_id', '=', $brand)->orderBy('id');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the subquery in EXISTS - both `*` and `ORDER BY` are excess.

Comment: @Akina do you have a link that 1 vs * makes a difference?  I thought there were no performance diff between the two.

Comment: *I thought there were no performance diff between the two.* You have tested this carefully and have ensured that there is no differense? or you only think so?

Comment: ...and LIMIT without ORDER BY (at the same level of query) is fairly meaningless

Comment: I tested it. Addig order by increase query execution time by 0.01ms

Comment: The `IF EXISTS()` only returns a boolean - true or false. It doesn't return any rows of data - so those `ORDER BY` clauses are utterly useless in those subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because brand_id cannot be both 7 and 24 for a given record.  You want "OR".  It would be clearer to just use the expression `brand_id in (7, 24)` instead of the two separate sub-queries.  There is no point in sorting the sub-query.

Alternatively, join the two tables:

```
select ...
from slasher_farming_mods m
join slasher_farming_brands b on m.brand_id = b.id
where brand_id in (7, 24)
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: I tried to sort subquery because, debugbar suggested to include order by to shorten execution cycle. But it made not difference.

Comment: This solution works like a charm. Also tried adding OR instead of AND and it also works.